# Passing second parameter in a callback function Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, callback

Following is the code, which is working fine -

```
const print = x => {
  console.log(x)
}


const result = [1,2,3,4].forEach(print)
console.log(result)
```

But when I am trying to pass another variable to `print2` function I am getting an `undefined` error.

```
const print2 = (x, y) => {
  console.log(x * y)
}

const result = [1,2,3,4].forEach(print2(x, 10))
console.log(result)
```

I am going through the callback function chapter, so please spare me if something very common I missed here.

Comment: Use `.forEach(x => print2(x, 10))`. And note that `forEach` does not return anything, your `result` variable is thus undefined.

Comment: @str if my question was not closed, I would love to accept your comment as an answer ..thx +1